# DOM handling using marklogic java client api

Tags: java, dom, nosql, marklogic, marklogic-8

I'm new to MarkLogic java API and trying to create an xml document where `Document` is constructed using `DocumentBuilderFactory` and `DocumentBuilder` and everything is working fine with the following code.

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory factory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
 DocumentBuilder docBuilder=factory.newDocumentBuilder();
 Document doc=docBuilder.newDocument();  //Works fine
```

Now since I have doc reference I can call `doc.CreateElement()` to create an xml  structured document.

In the same way if I refer a Document using DOMHandle from com.marklogic.client.io.DOMHandle;

```
 DOMHandle handle=new DOMHandle();
 Document doc=handle.get();
 doc.createElement();         //NULL POINTER EXCEPTION
```

Now the document reference created from handle gives an null pointer exception.
I understood that I am getting document from a getter method which returns an empty document but I am not trying to access anything from the empty document. Instead trying to create a document element using `doc.createElement()` where null pointer exception is arising.

Please explain the issue.

Answer (score 3):

A `DOMHandle` represents XML content as a DOM Document. It is not a factory which would create a DOM Document. The handle is just an adapter that wraps a document that we read from the database or create in Java. Unless explicitly set with the constructor `DOMHandle(Document content)` or with the method `public void set(Document content)`, the content of the DOMHandle would be null and hence the `NullPointerException`. You should probably do one of these

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder=factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc=docBuilder.newDocument();
// Build the Document completely and assign it to the handle and use the handle
DOMHandle handle = new DOMHandle(); 
handle.set(doc);
// or DOMHandle handle = new DOMHandle(doc); 
// or DOMHandle handle = new DOMHandle().with(doc);
```